Report Job not sending for CSV
I am trying to automate sending a report to my email. When I manually click execute on the scheduler, for pdf, it takes me to a different screen showing the report, but still sends the email. For csv, it downloads the csv on my personal machine, but never sends the email (seems like it is getting stuck in trying to send it).
These are my parameters:
instanceId=46
format=csv
sendmail=1
I think I set everything up right. I am not sure if it is an issue with me manually executing rather than waiting for the cron job to execute on its own. I'm not sure why it is trying to install the csv on my personal machine since sendmail is 1.
--Edit adding screenshots as suggested/

This is where I am clicking execute and the parameters I have.

When I click execute here, the csv gets downloaded to my local pc, but never gets sent to my email. I also can't click cancel after the fact.

This is the log after I click the back arrow to get out. It looks like the job starts, but it freezes and never completes.

Could you please add some screenshots?  It might help people to better understand your situation.
